# Company of Heroes 2: Can same faction play against each other in multiplayer?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

I thinking about buying company of heroes 2.
I have played company of heroes 1.
There it was not possible to play with same faction against in other in multiplayer (e.g. germans vs. germans.)
So is it possible in Company of Heroes 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is no axis vs allies restriction in CoH2.

Comment: In automatch there is restriction. It is allways germans vs the rest.